# Getting Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I am using **Django, DRF , docker, Nginx and  AWS EC2 instance** for my personal project, application is working fine when it is using HTTP , once i changed to HTTPS i am getting CSRF Verification Failed.

used {% csrf_token %} where required in html forms

in `settings.py` I have:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost/', 'example.co.in', 'www.example.co.in']

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost/', 'example.co.in', 'www.example.co.in']
```

Please help me in solving this issue, thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the "https://" in the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, you have "http://" in your settings and this is why with http works but not with https.